# Retrieve XElement's children as top level of object

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

When using the `XElement` API and asking for a particular element (via `.Element("Foo")`), I get back an object which, when serialized to JSON (using ASP.NET Core), results in an object with a single field (Foo), which then contains all of the child objects of Foo.

How do I make it so that all of the children of Foo are contained in the top level of the serialized object? The `.Elements()` method will get me the elements but I don't want them as a collection, I want them as fields on an object.

Comment: Create your class and serialize instances of this one instead of serializing `XElements`?

Comment: I literally just want an object that's a property of some XML returned from an API as-is, so I want to avoid creating a ton of brittle boilerplate XML POCOs if at all possible.

Comment: Create a custom serializer then.

Comment: That would involve having to create the boilerplate POCOs I said I wanted to avoid. It doesn't look like I'm going to avoid doing that, though. :-(

Comment: Apparently not since you already have tried how an `XElement` is serialized using the default serializer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not satisfied with how an `XElement` is serialized by the default serializer, you basically have two options.

1. Create your custom type and serialize instances of this one.
2. Create a custom converter for either `XElement` or your custom type.

If you are using System.Text.Json, which is the default one in ASP.NET Core 3.x, you inherit from `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<T>` and override the `Read` and `Write` methods.

If you are still using Newtonsoft.Json, you inherit from `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter<T>` and override the `ReadJson` and `WriteJson` methods.